# Property-placeholder default value separator

Tags: spring, configuration, properties, placeholder

Small question.
We use Spring 3.1 and seem to be having an issue with the value separator (The default value that is).

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="false" ignore-unresolvable="false" location="${app-conf-base-path:classpath:}environment/app-conf-${spring.profiles.active:test}.properties" />
```

We filter the properties being deployed based on maven environment profiles. If no maven environment profile was provided all environment property files will loaded in the war and put on the classpath. 
The actual environment specific settings are loaded at runtime using spring profiles. The part that is giving us an issue though is ${app-conf-base-path:classpath:} because it seems he can not resolve this. I believe this is because the placeholder is split using the last occurrence of the default value separator.
Why we want this is because we want him to look on the app-conf-base-path unless this is not defined as JVM parameter. In that case he should look in the classpath.

I tried:

- Placeholder configurer with a value separator == '?' with no avail.

Anyone got an idea of an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making sure external configuration files are added to the classpath of the server when loading it's classloaders. This way I don't need a placeholder to point to a file:// type location.
I added a export line to the setclasspath.sh of tomcat to add the external file to the environment variable CLASSPATH.